# How do I pass in an entire JSON as the cypress.env through the command line in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, json, testing, command-line, cypress

I am familiar with adding individual environment variables through the CLI by entering:

```
./node_modules/.bin/cypress run -- --env itemToOverride="val"
```

But let's say I have an entire JSON that can be a valid cypress.env, how do I pass that in via CLI without having to add each item from the JSON individually?

For example, let's say I have env1.json and env2.json which both have valid structure for my test, but I want to be able to run all my tests with env1 then env2? Similar to:

```
./node_modules/.bin/cypress run -- --env env1.json
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For others that stumble here and want a working answer: The easiest solution to this would be to create a config folder in your project directory containing all the environment JSONs you want. I wrote a script to take an environment file's name as an argument when running it. I decided on a bash script, but you could also use an npm script to achieve this. Basically, to run the tests in "env1" you would type on your command line:

```
./cypress --env=env1
```

The way I achieved this was by copying the selected JSON from the config folder to the main directory, then renaming it 'cypress.env.json'. This is a setup function in my bash script to get you started:

```
function doSetup {
  echo "Selecting environment variables from $ENV.env.json"
  cp ./cypress/config/"$ENV.env.json" ./
  mv "$ENV.env.json" "cypress.env.json"
}
```

It's an obscure problem that does not have very many answers online, but I hope this helps!